# Relative path of file does not get solved

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Apparently python takes every related importation in relation to the first called file.

I have the following file structure

```
src
 |--myunittests.py
 |--subfolder1
      |--__init__.py
      |--printFileContent.py
      |--subfolder2
           |--__init__.py
           |--file
```

**myunittests.py** will test the behavior of functions inside printFileContent:

```
from subfolder1.printFileContent import printFileContent
printFileContent()
```

**printFileContent** prints the content of a file contained inside the subfolder:

```
def printFileContent():
with open("./subfolder2/file") as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    printFileContent()
```

**file** just contains some text.

*Question:* 
Doing `python3 printFileContent.py` inside the subfolder1 will correctly output the file content.
But doing `python3 myunittests.py` raises the error, that the file could not be found.

Is there a way to solve this problem? (Is there a way to tell python, that files refered relative programmatically should be relative to the file they are used in?

**constraints**

- changing content inside printFileContent.py is not an option (generated file)
- Such calls of printFileContent are at arbitrary places throughout the code (A unittest file calls a dialog, that calls printFileContent vv inside subdirectory2)

*When does this behavior occur?*
When `file` is an icon that is used inside `printFileContent.py`, while printFileContent.py is called from myunittests.py

*Sidequestion:*
Is there a proper title/bulletpoint word for explaining / finding out about this behavior and problems with it?

Comment: You want to open `subfolder2/file` (2 missing in your question), right?

Comment: I corrected the typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot modify `printFileContent.py`, you can save the current directory, go to the directory of `subfolder1` and then come back to the original directory:

```
import subfolder1
import os

# Save current directory (absolute path)
cdir = os.path.abspath(os.path.curdir)

# Change directory, and call printFileContent
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(subfolder1.__file__))
subfolder1.printFileContent()

# Go back to the original directory
os.chdir(cdir)
```

If you have to use this a lot of time, you can make this behavior a class usable with a `with` statement so that it's easier to use and more robust (you won't forget to `chdir` back):

```
import os

class TmpDirChanger:
  def __init__(self, tmpPath):
    self.currentDir = os.path.abspath(os.path.curdir)
    os.chdir(tmpPath)

  def __enter__(self): pass

  def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
    #change back to original dir
    os.chdir(self.currentDir)

with TmpDirChanger('path/to/some/dir'):
   do_something()
```

---

If you can modify `printFileContent.py`, it is less tricky:

```
import os

def printFileContent():
    # This will give you path to subfolder1
    sfolder1 = os.path.dirname(__file__)

    # This will give you path to "file" in subfolder2
    name = os.path.join(sfolder1, 'subfolder2', 'file')

    with open(name) as file:
        for line in file:
            print(line)
```

Comment: I added the constraint, that that file is not changable. But your answer is valid in case of changable files.

Comment: I have about 30 places where calls are made, so I was hoping for a more general answer. As I also have similar problems with python includes. It seems best to never have a subdirectory inside a subdirectory in python. But this answer basically solved my problem. So I'll accept it as answer. Thank you for the quick help.